# Get integer array from stored Flag Enum value

Tags: .net, vb.net, enums

Not sure how to phrase the question, so forgive me.

I am using Aforge.Controls.Joystick to store a gamepad button press combo as an integer. IT uses a Flag Enumerator for the button(s) press - e.g. Button 1 returns decimal 1, Button 2 decimal 2 and Button 1 and 2 together 3 (2+1).

I am storing this decimal in an ini for use in another class. What I am needing to do is retrieve this decimal in another class and construct an integer array of which buttons are pressed (essentially, which bits are true/1). Some examples:

Retrieved Decimal:   3
Returns:   1,2

Retrieved Decimal:   16
Returns:   5

Retrieved Decimal:   22
returns:   5,3,2

I know I'm missing something blindingly obvious, but getting lost in all the concepts (e.g. bitwise, flag enums etc etc)

Would appreciate any help...

EDIT1: Following comments:

Have to use an ini as storing this value between application runs.

Following confusion, the enumerator for the joystick would look something like this:

```
<Flags> Public Enum Pets
   Button1 = 1
   Button2 = 2
   Button3 = 4
   Button4 = 8
   Button5 = 16
End Enum
```

Therefore "22" would be Buttons 5,3 and 2 (16+4+2)

---

EDIT2: Following reply 1

Tried:

```
        Imports AForge.Controls
        Imports AForge

        Dim txt = "22"            ' value from "ini"
        ' parse back into an enum
        Dim ButtonsPress As Joystick.Buttons = CType([Enum].Parse(GetType(Joystick.Buttons), txt), Joystick.Buttons)

        Dim picks = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(Joystick.Buttons)).
                Cast(Of Joystick.Buttons).
                Where(Function(q) ButtonsPress.HasFlag(q)).
                ToArray()

        For Each v As Joystick.Buttons In picks
            Console.WriteLine(v.ToString())
        Next
```

However, it will not compile:

```
  'HasFlag' is not a member of 'AForge.Controls.Joystick.Buttons'
```

However, when I check Joystick.Buttons in Object browser, summary reads:
"Flags enumeration of joystick buttons."

Puzzled...

EDIT3 - Solved

Answer combo of comments and answer below. To get the specific numbers back as per original question:

```
        Dim txt = "22"            ' value from "ini"
        Dim ButtonsPress As Joystick.Buttons = CType([Enum].Parse(GetType(Joystick.Buttons), txt), Joystick.Buttons)
        Dim picks = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(Joystick.Buttons)).
                Cast(Of Joystick.Buttons).
                Where(Function(q) (ButtonsPress And q) = q).
                ToArray()
        For Each v As Joystick.Buttons In picks
            Console.WriteLine(v.ToString().Remove(0, 6))
        Next
```

Produces:

```
2
3
5
```

Comment: Decimal: 16 Returns: 5

Decimal: 22 returns: 5,3,2 This makes no sense. Explain. Then why you use ini? Thats only good if you want to store information for some later time or each software initialization. Doesn't look like your case. Why not store those integers in array and pass array to method in other class?

Comment: rather than writing to a file to pass data, just pass the typed data. then you can test it as it is mean to be used

Comment: Not sure it doesn't make sense, Claudius - please see edit1 above. Overall, I am needing to store the decimal value in the ini for later retrieval. I could include the AForge library in the second class to access the enumerator if that would make solution achievable..

Comment: `HasFlag` is a standard function for a NET enum.  Of course, I have no idea what AForge is about.  Try the long form: `Where(Function(q) (p And q) = q)`

Comment: That did the trick - thanks! Have posted in OP final solution to get the specific numbers back minus the "Button" prefix from the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step, get the stored value back into an Enum type:

```
Dim txt = "22"            ' value from "ini"
' parse back into an enum
Dim p As Pets = CType([Enum].Parse(GetType(Pets), txt), Pets)
```

These 2 steps could be skipped if the data was serialized as typed data rather than stored as text.  Then, get an array of the Enum values represented:

```
Dim picks = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(Pets)).
                    Cast(Of Pets).
                    Where(Function(q) p.HasFlag(q)).
                    ToArray()
```

An alternative to `HasFlag` is the long form: `Where(Function(q) (p And q) = q)`.  Then test it:

```
For Each v As Pets In picks
    Console.WriteLine(v.ToString())
Next
```

If you want to print/see the integer values instead of the name, use `Console.WriteLine(v)`

Result:

> Button2
>   Button3
>   Button5

---

One caveat with this is when the Enum can include combos:

```
<Flags> Public Enum Buttons
    A = 1
    B = 2
    AB = 3
    C = 4
    D = 8
    E = 16
    All = 31
End Enum
```

When the value is 3, the array will include {A, B, AB} effectively including each twice.  A value of 31 would have all 7 elements.

Comment: Thanks man - that looks like it's getting close. However, have a compile error, please see EDIT2 in OP.